# Set hadoop user to launch spark-submit via oozie shell action

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I want to set hadoop user for spark-submit action when launching oozie workflow via shell action: oozie MR (that launches shell) should launch as user A, but spark-submit (that is started from shell script) should launch as user B.

I tried to set user.name=A (in job.properties) with 'export HADOOP_USER_NAME=B' (in shell script) but it doesn't work unless A=B.

Can anyone help?

P.S. I'm using oozie 4.0.0 with CDH 5.3.1 and spark 1.2.0 on yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised exporting the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` in the shell script isn't working, but you might try adding a

```
<shell ...>
  ...
  <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=B</env-var>
  ...
</shell>
```

to the shell action in the xml.

Comment: sorry, can't check it anymore, we already moved to another solution for submitting spark jobs, and spark\oozie\cdh versions has changed